# Search button not working in instant search with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have tried instant search using jQuery. It is working fine until I click the search button. When I click the search button the page will reload and the results would disappear.

Here's my code:

search.php

```
<div id="search-container">
    <form action="search.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="key" id="key" placeholder="search" onkeydown="searchIt();"></input>
        <input type="submit" name="search" id="search" value="search"></input>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="res-container"></div>
```

And the script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function searchIt(){
        var text = $("input[name='key']").val();
        text = text.trim();
        if(text.length>3){
            $.post("query.php",{index: text}, function(data){
                $("#res-container").html(data);
            });
        }
    }       
</script>
```

query.php

```
if(isset($_POST['index'])){
$key = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['index']);        
$key = trim($key);
$result = "";
if(!empty($key)){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name LIKE '%$key%' OR  last_name LIKE '%$key%'";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($query_run);

    if($row_count == 0){
        $result = "No results!!!";
    }else{
         while($query_row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run)){
            $fname = $query_row['first_name'];
            $lname = $query_row['last_name'];
            $name = $fname.' '.$lname;      

            $mail = $query_row['email_id'];
            $id = $query_row['emp_id'];

            $result .="<div class=\"qitems\"><div class=\"name\"><a href=\"\">$name</a></div><div class=\"mail\">$mail</div></div>";
        }
    }
  }else{
    $result = 'please enter a word';
}
}
echo ($result);
```

Until this everthing is working fine, but when I try to click search button the results would disappear.

I tried adding this in the script:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[name='search']").click(searchIt());
});
```

But there is no change. Please help me with this.

Comment: Try to follow @Alex N answer and later on, my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('body').on('click', 'input[name="search"]', function(event)
     {
            event.preventDefault(); // This is important, since you are interacting with a valid html form/element
            searchIt();
     });
});
```

Update:

I've made a codepen for you. Look at it, it works perfectly fine:
http://codepen.io/dschu/pen/VmRJPZ

Comment: i am getting the same problem... i am not getting any results after clicking the button!!! There is no error in console too!!!

Comment: if i add event.preventDefault(); i am getting errors in console

Comment: Again: What's the exact error message? Just paste it as comment.

Comment: search.php:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '    preventDefault' of undefined
    at searchIt (search.php:21)
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup (search.php:40)

Comment: Does your searchIt() function contains a "e.preventDefault"? If there is no object named "e" or "event", then you a calling a property of an undefined object. Also: I've updated my answer, which includes a working example on codepen now.

Comment: yw, glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is button of type "submit" effectively submits the page to form URL, which is the same page, thus has the same effect, as reloading, - here is your "reset" behaviour. Besides solution above you can also change input type from `submit` to `button`, which will avoid submitting the form (and manually preventing the event).